# How do I perform complex queries on Entity data?

Tags: entity

I'd like to query, for example, the `Entity["MusicWork"]` data for something like "all music works whose names contain the word 'Funk'". Or even "plot a date histogram by year of the number of works whose name contains the word 'Funk', as a fraction of the total number of works".

I can easily get all the works with some exact name:

```
EntityList[
  Entity["MusicWork", {"Name" -> "Jump"}]]
```

I can query for works released within some time interval:

```
EntityList[
  Entity["MusicWork", {"FirstRecordingDate" -> DateObject[{2006}]}]]
```

But I'd like to query for a pattern in the `"Name"` property, but I'm unable to glean from the documentation what type of expression I can use here.

Comment: I you want to edit your question a lot, please do it in a separate paragraph. We don't want to end up with a question and a bunch of unrelated answers.

Comment: I edited the question because it got two answers about date intervals. While that's helpful, it's not really what the question is about.

Answer (score 1):

`Interval` needs `{` and `}`:

```
In[1]:= EntityList[
  EntityClass[
   "MusicWork", {"FirstRecordingDate" -> 
     Interval[{DateObject[{2006, 1}], 
       DateObject[{2006, 12}]}]}]] // Length

Out[1]= 3951
```

Implicitly defined entity classes do not support string matching inside property values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Interval` here, `DateObject[{2006}]` is a much better option here.

```
music2006 = 
  EntityList[
   Entity["MusicWork", {"FirstRecordingDate" -> DateObject[{2006}]}]];
```

You can filter this list of entities for works that contain the word "funk" using

```
Select[music2006, StringMatchQ[EntityValue[#, "Name"], ___ ~~ "funk" ~~ ___] &]
```

Comment: One might want to add `IgnoreCase -> True` as a `StringMatchQ[]` setting.

Comment: But doesn't `EntityValue` call out to the internet for each element?

Comment: @Apocalisp, it would be a good idea to cache the names (i.e. map `EntityValue[]` in one go) and do any subsequent searches on the cache afterwards.