# How to use an EntityClass

Tags: curated-data, geographics, entity

The two formats documented for `EntityClass` are

```
EntityClass["type",name]
EntityClass["type",{property1->value1, property2->value2}]
```

It appears as if my intended use would require input of the form below, which is not allowed.

```
EntityClass["type",name,{property1->value1, property2->value2}]
```

I am attempting to find the 100 public high schools closest to my college.

```
(* Let's say my college is in Brockport, NY *)
bport = Entity["City",{"Brockport", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}]["Position"];
(* Get public high school data *)
ps = EntityClass["PublicSchool", {"USState", "NewYork"}];
```

Right now, I'm using two steps to cull the desired information from the `EntityClass`.  First, I create a list of schools with their distances to Brockport and their grade spans, then filter the (sorted) list to exclude schools that serve students below 7th grade.

```
distanceToBPort = 
 MapThread[{#3, #1, GeoDistance[bport, #2]} &, 
 Transpose@ps[{"Name", "Coordinates", "GradeSpan"}]];
subset = SortBy[
   Select[distanceToBPort, (#[[1]] =!= Missing["NotAvailable"]) && ( 
       Head[#[[3]]] =!= GeoDistance) &&
      Not@MemberQ[#[[1]], "pre-kindergarten" | "kindergarten", 2] &&
      #[[1, 1]] > 6
     &
    ], Last];
```

The selection/filtering is not optimal and probably removes valid entries, but the point here is that I *should* be able to create an implicit entity class rather than converting into a `List`.  My approach, as presented, eliminates the location information, which I need to create a map, although I can work around that by redesigning the `MapThread` statement.

**The question:** What is the appropriate, effective way to filter an EntityClass defined by `EntityClass["type",name]` while maintaining an Entity-type head?

A [similar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98058/7167) question has been asked; however, I don't think it relates to the current problem (unless I'm completely misinterpreting the relationship between the 2nd argument types in `EntityClass`).

Comment: `EntityClass[..., name]` is pretty much just a short-hand for `EntityClass[..., filteringRules]`, even if the filter is `"Name"->MemberQ[nameAlternatives]`. What you'll want is `EntityClass["PublicSchool", {"State"->..., "Location"->TakeSmallestBy[distanceToBrockPort, 10]]` or something.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I'm not sure how to implement that suggestion, since the components of name ("USState" and "NewYork") are not properties of the school entities that are in the EntityClass.

Comment: There’s surely some form of location property right? You can do the filtering off that I imagine

Comment: To find the nearest high schools I'd use ``schools = GeoNearest[ps, bport, 100]``. You can check the distances with ``GeoDistance[bport, schools]``.

Comment: @jose that's getting me in the right direction

Comment: That's interesting. My undergraduate alma mater is in that town, specifically I worked with professors whose labs are in the basement of your building. :)

Comment: @rcollyer Small world.  That department has nearly turned over.  Should be some exciting things happening in the near future.

Comment: @bobthechemist i didn't associate terribly much with your dept. having only two classes with them (required for graduation). Among the basement dwellers, only one person from my time there (I came in with your lab manager's older brother) is still there. So, definitely a small world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a workaround. If you're willing and able to preload the data, you could create your own custom `Entity` type with [`EntityStore`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityStore.html) and treat it as if it were a built in.

Your data:

```
bport = Entity["City", {"Brockport", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}]["Position"];
ps = EntityClass["PublicSchool", {"USState", "NewYork"}];
```

The nearby schools, per Jose's comment above:

```
ents = GeoNearest[ps, bport, 100];
```

Create the custom entity. For brevity I omit custom labels, properties, classes, etc.

```
store = EntityStore[
  "NearbyPublicSchools" -> <|
    "Entities" -> EntityValue[ents, "EntityPropertyAssociation"]
  |>
];

EntityRegister[store];
```

Query as if it were a built in type. For example:

```
largefaculty = EntityClass["NearbyPublicSchools", 
  {"TotalTeachers" -> GreaterThan[Quantity[50, "People"]]}];

largefaculty["EntityCount"]
```

> ```
> 28
> ```

```
GeoListPlot[largefaculty]
```

[image]

---

Here's another workaround, but unfortunately your example returns `Missing["QueryTooSlow"]`.

```
EntityClass["PublicSchool", 
  {"Entity" -> ps, "TotalTeachers" -> GreaterThan[Quantity[200, "People"]]}
]["EntityCount"]
```

> ```
> Missing["QueryTooSlow", {"PublicSchool", {EntityProperty["PublicSchool", "Entity"] -> EntityClass["PublicSchool", {"USState", "NewYork"}]}}]
> ```

Here's a smaller example:

```
EntityClass["Lattice", 
  {"Entity" -> EntityClass["Lattice", "Even"], "Determinant" -> GreaterThan[10]}
]["EntityCount"]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

Comment: It may be a workaround; however, I'm doubtful that a non-workaround answer is available with the current version of Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

Nominally this should work as a pure `EntityClass` query...

```
EntityClass[
  "PublicSchool",
  {
   "Position" ->
    TakeSmallestBy[
     With[{h = Here},
      If[MissingQ[#], Quantity[ 10^10, "Miles"], GeoDistance[#, h]] &
      ], 
     10
     ]
   }
  ] // EntityList
```

But it'll be slow as no pre-curation has been done. Making subqueries on an `EntityClass` doesn't seem to be supported. I'm not sure how this could be sped up, though, and I haven't had the patience to wait for the query to finish.